# c++ friend class as argument for ctor

Tags: c++, class, friend

I am wondering how come this code correct and how the compiler knows to first create an obj of class A, I would think it shouldn't compile since B's ctor request an argument of type A not int

```
    class A 
{
    int a1;
public:
    A(int i) { cout << i << "A"<<endl;}
    friend class B;
};

class B
{
public:
    B(A a) {cout <<"B" <<a.a1;}
};

void main() 
{
    B b(7);
}
```

output: 7A
        B7

Comment: Add explicit to A(int) constructor to prevent this behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `friend`.

Because you haven't marked the `A` constructor `explicit`, an implicit conversion from `int` to `A` occurs.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is smart enough to think Got an int .... need and A - Wait here is the constructor. Use that

Comment: _"The friend bit is not required."_ It actually is: `B(A a) {cout <<"B" <<a.a1;}`

Comment: My fault - sunday morning. forgot defaults to private

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the compiler calls the constructor A implicitly (because A(int)), so your code is equivalent to:

```cpp
B b(A(7));
```